# conformal mapping (complex analysis )

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

let $f$ be an entire function on **C**.Let $ g(z)=\overline f(\overline z)$ .Which of the following statements are correct?

(A)  If $f(z) \in \mathbb R $ for all $z\in \mathbb R$ then $f=g$

(B)  If $f(z) \in \mathbb R $ for all $z\in \{ z:Imz=0 \}\cup\{ z:Imz=a \}$ for some $a>0$,then $f(z+ia)=f(z-ia)$ for all $z\in \mathbb C$

(C)If $f(z) \in \mathbb R $ for all $z\in \{ z:Imz=0 \}\cup\{ z:Imz=a \}$ for some $a>0$,then $f(z+2ia)=f(z)$ for all $z\in \mathbb C$

(D)If $f(z) \in \mathbb R $ for all $z\in \{ z:Imz=0 \}\cup\{ z:Imz=a \}$ for some $a>0$,then $f(z+ia)=f(z)$ for all $z\in \mathbb C$

What I have done is to consider z=x+iy and $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$. Now (A) is clearly not true .For (B) I know $v(x,0)=v(x,a)=0$ what can we say about $v(x,-a), u(x,-a)$ when u and v both are differentiable?

I don't know how to proceed any further. Please help.I know bilinear map and cross ratio but i don't know how to use them here.Thanks.

Comment: If $f$ is entire then $$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n, \qquad c_n = \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} \in \mathbb{C}$$
What happens if $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \ f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ ? Can you see how it is related to (B,C,D) ?

Comment: I am sorry i could not get your point. I am still an amateur for this course. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: What happens if $f(x)$ is real for $x$ real ? What does it mean for $n$-th derivatives $f^{(n)}(x)$ ?

Comment: To know $f^{(n)}(x)$ we need f(x) which is u(x,y) for $ x\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: So ? Can you plug this into the power series ? What do you obtain ?

Comment: am i right if i say $c_n$ is real. So f(z) =$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n, \qquad c_n = \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} \in \mathbb{R}$ but still f(z+ia) is not equal to f(z-ia)

Comment: So $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n$ with $c_n \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus $\overline{f(\overline{z})} = ?$

Comment: No interruption but will that derivative be zero (may be not as we donot know whether f is constant or not) , also $f^{n}(x)$ has to real! @user1952009